# Como compilar solo los ficheros modificados en gulp.watch

Tags: nodejs, gulp

Tengo un proyecto de typescript y estoy usando gulp como *task manager*. 
Quiero que la tarea `gulp watch` se quede esperando a que se modifique el codigo fuente y me lo vuelva a compilar, pero como el codigo fuente es muy largo y esta dividio en varios ficheros quiero que solo recompile los que se modifiquen y no todos. 
Con `gulp.watch(src, ['compile-src']);` ejecuto la tarea `compile-src` cada vez que se modifica cualquier fichero, pero `compile-src` me compila todos los ficheros.

Este es mi gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
// gulp + typescript specifics
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const ts = typescript.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

const src = ['./src/**/*.ts', './test/**/*.ts'];

gulp.task('compile-src', () => {
    ts.src()
        .pipe(ts())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['compile-src'], () => {
    gulp.watch(src, ['compile-src']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

en Visual Studio Code, abro solo los que voy a modificar. En terminal integrado (sobre el archivo modificado abierto) pongo en línea de comando gulp sass; y me compila solo ese archivo.